# Laravel Elixir and Bootstrap's JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-elixir

I'm using ES6 syntax to import stuff into my app.js browserify file like so:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap-sass';
```

And still, I'm getting the following error:

```
bundle.js:3 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

When I check `bundle.js` file, both the Bootstrap JS and jQuery are in there but in different order (Bootstrap always comes first). I tried switching them around when loading, but still the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load first `jquery` library and then load `bootstrap` library. Also check that you have used latest `jquery` library.

If still the same errors there : Then it might be `conflict` with other `jQuery` library.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve. So how should I load jquery first? These are the only 2 libraries I'm loading at the moment